# Disabling jQuery function after its been called

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

How can I prevent this function from calling itself again:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    login();
});

function login() {
    $('#login').hide();
    $('#pre-login button').on('click',function(event) {
        $('#pre-login').hide();
        $('#login').show();
        $('#login :text').focus();
        return false;
    });
}
```

I have these two forms:

```
<form id="pre-login"><p>Already have an account?</p><button type="submit">Login</button></form>
<form id="login">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" class="login">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="login"><h4><a href="#">Forgot?</a></h4>
    <button type="submit" class="action">Login</button>
</form>
```

The first form is displayed when the page has been load, while the second form is set to hidden. Upon clicking the login button on the first form the second form is shown, making the first hidden. However, clicking the login button on the second form is causing a reverse effect, even though I'm telling jQuery to only call the function when a button of #pre-login form is clicked.

I can't make heads or tails what's going on here so I'm thinking maybe it's just best to disable the function once it's been called once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method:

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element.

```
function login() {
    $('#login').hide();
    $('#pre-login button').one('click',function(event) {
        $('#pre-login').hide();
        $('#login').show();
        $('#login :text').focus();
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: Just tried this out and was unsuccessful, but it seems that it should work. It must be something with the way I'm calling the function.

Comment: @rick Do you generate the `button` element dynamically?

Comment: are you possibly running `login()` multiple times?

Comment: @KevinB just checked and I'm only calling it once.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure it's the Javascript causing what you see?  I set this up in a basic [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cincodenada/RARnS/1/), and it appears that the second Login button is just reloading the page (and submitting the login form data to it), thus resetting it to the initial state.  This would make it look like the Javascript is re-hiding itself, but in reality it would just be doing what you told it to - that is, starting hidden.

If you're going to be working with Javascript, be sure to use Firebug in Firefox, or Chrome's Developer Tools - they're brilliant for stepping through the Javascript and monitoring requests to see what's happening.

My guess is that when you get the additional checking put in to accept logins and display a "Logged In" message when a user is logged in, everything will work as expected.

Comment: You're right — it appears this is actually what's happening. My localhost was reloading so quickly I didn't even notice the page was actually refreshing. Embarrassing...Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use .one() . This makes sure the event is only executed once..

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    login();
});

function login() {
    $('#login').hide();
    $('#pre-login button').one('click',function(event) {
        $('#pre-login').hide();
        $('#login').show();
        $('#login :text').focus();
        return false;
    });
}
```

// You can also Unbind it when the the click event is executed..

```
function login() {
        $('#login').hide();
        $('#pre-login button').one('click',function(event) {
            $('#pre-login').hide();
            $('#login').show();
            $('#login :text').focus();
            $(this).unbind();
            return false;
        });
    }
```